# Help needed in the following code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can we assign the value of an object of an array having an image value to a variable of image view, see the following code

```
NSArray *imgArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Bingo2.png", nil];
    UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    img.image=[imgArray objectAtIndex:0];    //line 3
    [self.view addSubview:img];
```

its not working, Application is crashing i guess because of line 3

Please help me,
Many Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please place your code in code tags. It would be easier to read it then. Shouldn't you be adding an image to the array instead of a string?

Answer (score 4):

You are storing an NSString object in the array and not an image. That is why it is crashing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have changed my code and now adding the image to array but still its not working, actually I have an array of images and i want  to  store one image of the array into an another image view variable,how will i do that, as I think we dont directly do that, we have to do some type casting here, pls help me in that,  thanks again for your help

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
img.image= [UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

instead of

```
img.image=[imgArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

if the above doesn't work

than you can also use this

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [imgArray objectAtIndex:0]];
img.image= [UIImage imageNamed:string];
```

Comment: Thanks Robin, I have tried both the way but its still not working, giving NSException Erro, pls help me again

Comment: can you post the NSException Error in the question

Answer (score 1):

You have a string of a filename in your array, not an image. Use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bingo2.png"]` instead.

Comment: Many Thanks for your help,I have changed it as you written but still its not working, basically I have an array of images and i want  to  store one image of the array into an another image view variable,how will i do that, pls help me, thanks again for your help